# What transforms a cosine into a sine?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, transformation

Do you know of any transform/application that turns a cosine into a sine, other than the Hilbert transform?

If the Hilbert transform is the only one, is there a simple reason for that?

I mean a neat transform like $T[cos(kx)]=sin(kx)$, with no additional constant popping up, just the function changing, so no derivative or similar!

Comment: The obvious transform is a phase shift of $\pi/2$.  $cos(kx-\pi/2)=sin(kx)$.

Comment: Do you only want to transform a specific cosine into a specific sine or do you want the (much stronger) property you stated in your third sentence, $T(\cos kx) = \sin kx$? If the latter, for what values of $k$?

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, I want the property of the third sentence, for any k real and x real.

Comment: The Hilbert transform itself doesn't have that property! We have $H(\cos \omega t) = \text{sgn}(\omega) \sin \omega t$.